# How to get an entry url from EVENT_AFTER_SAVE_ELEMENT callback?

Tags: plugin-development, craft3, events

In my plugin I am registering a callback for `Elements::EVENT_AFTER_SAVE_ELEMENT` event. Previously, in Craft2, I could access the URL of the saved entry from the `$event` parameter passed into the callback, like so: `$event->params['entry']->getUrl()`.

However I can't figure out how to get a reference to the entry in the Event model in Craft 3. If I `var_dump($event)` I can see the data I want nested deep inside a private property which I cannot access.

How do I access the entry data from the event in Craft 3?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check out the definition of the `ElementEvent` that you're passed:

```
class ElementEvent extends Event
{
    // Properties
    // =========================================================================

    /**
     * @var ElementInterface|null The element model associated with the event.
     */
    public $element;

    /**
     * @var bool Whether the element is brand new
     */
    public $isNew = false;
}
```

So you can access the element (in your case, presumably an `Entry`) via:

```
$event->element
```

Make sure to check for `null`, and depending on how you set up the event listener, that the element is of the type of you're looking for.

For instance, if you want only listen to `all` elements that are saved, you'd do:

```
    Event::on(
        Elements::class,
        Elements::EVENT_AFTER_SAVE_ELEMENT,
        function (ElementEvent $event) {
            Craft::debug(
                'Elements::EVENT_AFTER_SAVE_ELEMENT',
                __METHOD__
            );
        }
    );
```

...but if you only care about `Entry` elements, you'd do:

```
    Event::on(
        Entry::class,
        Entry::EVENT_AFTER_SAVE,
        function (ModelEvent $event) {
            Craft::debug(
                'Entry::EVENT_AFTER_SAVE',
                __METHOD__
            );
        }
    );
```

Comment: Ah it seems I have much to learn about Craft's new event model. I think my callback was getting called multiple times and the first time I just happened to be looking at a matrix. I tried your code with `Entry::class` instead of `Elements::class` but the callback never gets called. Is there something obvious I might be missing?

Comment: Ended up getting it working with this:
`Event::on(Entry::class, Entry::EVENT_AFTER_SAVE, function (Event $event) {});`

Comment: My bad, copy and paste error, I fixed the original answer